# Showing that x^T A is the transpose of Ax

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm following the linear algebra review pdf put together by Stanford which can be found [here](https://cs229.stanford.edu/lectures-spring2022/cs229-linear_algebra_review.pdf).  In the pdf, it is shown how to compute matrix-vector products, including both cases where the vector is to the right matrix, $y = Ax$, and to the left of the matrix, $y^T = x^TA$. This is shown here:

[image]

[image]

I attempted to calculate each entry out to show for myself that $x^TA$ is the transpose of $Ax$ as shown below.

$ y = Ax = 
\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2 + a_{13}x_3 \\ 
                a_{21}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{23}x_3\\
                a_{31}x_1 + a_{32}x_2 + a_{33}x_3\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

$ y = x^TA = 
\begin{bmatrix} x_2 & x_2 & x_3\\ \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\ \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}x_1 + a_{21}x_2 + a_{31}x_3, & 
                a_{12}x_1 + a_{22}x_2 + a_{32}x_3, &
                a_{13}x_1 + a_{23}x_2 + a_{33}x_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

However, I either made a mistake or misunderstood the meaning of the notation.  How is $x^TA$ is the transpose of $Ax$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. The correct general statement is that $(Ax)^T = x^TA^T$, which matches what you have computed. The two are only equal in the case where $A$ is a *symmetric* matrix, that is, $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$, or $A=A^T$ for short.

The confusion is coming from the fact that the $y$'s used in consecutive lines of the images you posted are not the same but are instead representing arbitrary vectors denoting the output of these computations.